# Reading from a textfile and populating textboxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, readfile

Ok, here is my current code. I'm having trouble reading in the file and populating the textboxes accordingly. After loading the file (I think that is) nothing is being populated in any of the textboxes listed below. Basically I'm not sure if the file is being read or not.

Any suggestions?

```
        If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("path_to_file") Then
            Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("path_to_file" + "filename")
            TextBox1.Text = ioFile.ReadLine() 'Adds the first line
            TextBox2.Text = ioFile.ReadLine() 'Adds the second line
            TextBox3.Text = ioFile.ReadLine() 'Adds the third line
            TextBox4.Text = ioFile.ReadLine() 'Adds the fourth line
            TextBox5.Text = ioFile.ReadLine() 'Adds the fifth line
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: You need to tell us what the "trouble" is that you are having. What's wrong with the code as it stands? Does it not work? Are the lines mixed up? What?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. But nothing is being populated in any of the textboxes I have listed, so I'm not sure if it actually reading the file or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm whats this

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("path_to_file") Then
  Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("path_to_file" + "filename")
```

should be

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(OpenFileDialog2.FileName) Then
  Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)
```

Comment: as a footnote, OpenFileDialog has a property, that means you can only select an existing file. If you are going to use it to avoid the FileExists check set the property in code though.

Comment: Hello, where do you define the path? C:\Users\ etc?

Comment: Wherever is best for you. If its in the same folder as the code, you don't need one.